# How to track an off-topic question that will soon be migrated to another (appropriate) SE network?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Is there a possibility of tracking the whereabouts of an off -topic question to the destination site if a user is interested in answering that particular question.

I will give an example; let's a question is asked on Android enthusiasts and it is evident that it does not belong there (i.e not within the scope defined in the [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) but fits perfectly on sister sites such as SuperUser SE or Software Recommendations SE, how can the user track this question to the respective site it fits so they can be able to answer it.

e.g this question [How to convert primary partition to logical on secondary Partition Windows 10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191077/how-to-convert-primary-partition-to-logical-on-secondary-partition-windows-10) which was asked on Android SE, doesn't fit there but instead SuperUser SE is an appropriate site for such a question. So how I can I track it  in the migration process until I can be able to answer it on SuperUser. Most of the time I was unsuccessful in tracking down such questions and ended giving up.

*Assuming the question is not immediately deleted* by the owner is there a mechanism that keeps the interested user **notified** until such a question can be deemed appropriate to be answered?

AFAICT an seemingly obvious workaround is taking down the link of the question, wait for the question to be put on hold first, then closed or eventually migrated.

However in all these instances you just have to keep checking manually too see if there any chances to the question, but still there is no good way to be notified of any of these changes, and it can be difficult to track this process daily until it is migrated.

Ideally what I had in mind is a feature similar to moderators tool priviledge which states:

> Access moderator tools
>
> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving
>   you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> .. **Recently migrated questions** ...

to be at least **made public** to avoid the hassle of checking link over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any way to get a notification, but after a question is migrated, the original question gets a banner to say what site it was migrated to, with a link to the question on the destination site.